# Running Fishers discriminate test in R

Tags: r

I have tried the following code to try and run fishers discriminant on my data set but it doesn't like the negative values.

```
Split_user <- user_col%>%
  select(-Heroin)%>%
   filter(User == "Yes")
Split_user1 <- Split_user%>%
  select(-User)
Split_nonuser <- user_col%>%
  select(-Heroin)%>%
  filter(User == "No")
Split_nonuser1 <- Split_user%>%
  select(-User)

#Calculate the Mean by class
m1 = colMeans(Split_user1)
m1
m2 = colMeans(Split_nonuser1)
m2
#Calculate the covariances by class
S1 = cov(Split_user1)
S2 = cov(Split_nonuser1)

dat <- data.frame(
  "User"=c(m1),
  "Non User" = c(m2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dat
test <- fisher.test(dat)
test
```

structure(list(Nscore = c(0.31287, -0.67825, -0.46725, -0.14882,
0.73545, -0.67825, -0.46725, -1.32828, 0.62967, -0.24649, -1.05308,
-1.32828, 2.28554, -0.79151, -0.92104, -2.05048, -1.55078, 0.52135,
1.37297, -0.34799, -0.79151, -1.1943, 0.41667, 1.60383, -0.14882
), Escore = c(-0.57545, 1.93886, 0.80523, -0.80615, -1.6334,
-0.30033, -1.09207, 1.93886, 2.57309, 0.00332, 0.80523, 0.00332,
0.16767, 0.80523, 1.45421, -1.50796, -0.80615, -1.23177, -0.15487,
-1.7625, 0.80523, 0.47617, -0.94779, -3.27393, 0.63779), Oscore = c(-0.58331,
1.43533, -0.84732, -0.01928, -0.45174, -1.55521, -0.45174, -0.84732,
-0.97631, -1.42424, -1.11902, 0.14143, 0.44585, -0.01928, 0.44585,
-1.55521, -1.68062, -0.31776, -0.17779, -2.39883, 0.7233, -1.11902,
-0.84732, -1.27553, 1.24033), Ascore = c(-0.91699, 0.76096, -1.6209,
0.59042, -0.30172, 2.03972, -0.30172, -0.30172, 0.76096, 0.59042,
-0.76096, -1.92595, -1.6209, 0.94156, -0.60633, -1.07533, 0.28783,
-0.45321, -1.92595, -1.92595, 1.61108, -0.60633, 1.11406, 0.28783,
0.76096), Cscore = c(-0.00665, -0.14277, -1.0145, 0.58489, 1.30612,
1.63088, 0.93949, 1.63088, 1.13407, 0.12331, 1.81175, -0.52745,
-0.78155, 3.46436, 1.63088, 1.13407, 0.7583, -1.38502, -1.5184,
0.7583, -1.13788, 1.81175, -0.89891, -1.0145, 1.46191), Impulsivity = c(-0.21712,
-0.71126, -1.37983, -1.37983, -0.21712, -1.37983, -0.21712, 0.19268,
-1.37983, -1.37983, 0.19268, 0.52975, 1.29221, -0.71126, 1.29221,
-0.71126, -0.21712, -1.37983, -0.71126, -1.37983, 0.19268, -0.21712,
-0.71126, -1.37983, -0.21712), SS = c(-1.18084, -0.21575, 0.40148,
-1.18084, -0.21575, -1.54858, 0.07987, -0.52593, -1.54858, -0.84637,
0.07987, 1.2247, 0.07987, -0.84637, 0.7654, -0.52593, -2.07848,
-0.84637, -0.21575, -2.07848, -0.21575, -1.18084, 0.07987, -1.54858,
-0.52593), Heroin = c("CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0",
"CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0",
"CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL0", "CL1",
"CL0"), User = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))

matrix - non negative enteries

structure(c(0.610545701853111, 0.96447451044118, 0.851040908078699,
0.589544977621028, 0.827711005318391, 0.904054295338232, 0.589544977621028,
0.456502942067452, 0.688702581355738, 0.533249474881585, 0.389562632031922,
0.456502942067452, 0.632276676717644, 0.436140184047234, 0.653498081085907,
0.166581403886779, 0.495545270523754, 0.476097331977154, 0.671587833703474,
0.533249474881585, 0.436140184047234, 0.71082275573317, 0.610545701853111,
0.550877805396231, 0.495545270523754, 0.606851082126989, 0.606851082126989,
0.529890274393643, 0.17257337601325, 0.40854553851544, 0.238467663593076,
0.327676651856099, 0.580185689487682, 0.367919991081809, 0.479144172121096,
1, 0.505317471692705, 0.453951873616486, 0.0885974551303489,
0.259420636058159, 0.505317471692705, 0.63189368241683, 0.386973070246684,
0, 0.327676651856099, 0.479144172121096, 0.327676651856099, 0.386973070246684,
0.350233306260252, 0.63189368241683, 0.535574626985272, 0.563618843854673,
0.750572944212062, 0.223135727679215, 0.4774929083129, 0.706259916342132,
0.355063144061413, 0.275029248201035, 0.667195538247031, 0.563618843854673,
0.850078930076767, 0.223135727679215, 0.796364408545283, 0.163192941968364,
0.223135727679215, 0.355063144061413, 0.163192941968364, 0.595629597576807,
0.4774929083129, 0.223135727679215, 0.535574626985272, 0.706259916342132,
0.508037245380387, 0.383103354327933, 0.414857685465647, 0.403077115158141,
0.233825658261037, 0.558377116170461, 0.712895943634026, 0.210211608610118,
0.285534960468907, 0.658493870402802, 0.429792238205629, 0.533600585795802,
0.210211608610118, 0.482206789967235, 0.684122436721568, 0.285534960468907,
0.456117618078684, 0.533600585795802, 0.508041194672498, 0.18731799331194,
0.456117618078684, 0.357934394919504, 0.712895943634026, 0.558377116170461,
0.558377116170461, 0.156244832950339, 0.581589612247721, 0.658493870402802,
0.318731025010843, 0.202385427208327, 0.202385427208327, 0.249965664305335,
0.406440653462484, 0.599528335983808, 0.498561515107706, 0.571262830706954,
0.571262830706954, 0.788549949400029, 0.694141246205002, 0.694141246205002,
0.729304611825936, 0.474472314587249, 0.429044383403209, 0.694141246205002,
0.36191629319069, 0.474472314587249, 0.154790732976724, 0.474472314587249,
0.429044383403209, 0.297072430244326, 0.474472314587249, 0.154790732976724,
0.406440653462484, 0.446013490788146, 0.757189169998879, 1, 0,
0.528084009118427, 0.446013490788146, 0.271569845659404, 0.624098434171681,
0.271569845659404, 0.528084009118427, 0.757189169998879, 0.528084009118427,
0.446013490788146, 0.367285305878396, 0.156155405657909, 0.271569845659404,
0.624098434171681, 0.757189169998879, 0.528084009118427, 0, 0.367285305878396,
0.528084009118427, 0.528084009118427, 0.156155405657909, 0.528084009118427,
0.825751648038478, 1, 0.619957452233758, 0.308011329405206, 0.619957452233758,
0.53955917314341, 0.710932676034508, 0.46565805295222, 0.53955917314341,
1, 0.825751648038478, 0.619957452233758, 0.825751648038478, 0.710932676034508,
0.619957452233758, 0.53955917314341, 1, 0.710932676034508, 0.710932676034508,
0.825751648038478, 0.825751648038478, 0.619957452233758, 0.46565805295222,
0, 0.825751648038478), dim = c(25L, 7L), dimnames = list(c("30",
"67", "115", "20", "3", "18", "16", "8", "10", "77", "84", "71",
"54", "64", "85", "105", "58", "2", "102", "17", "79", "87",
"63", "11", "39"), c("Nscore", "Escore", "Oscore", "Ascore",
"Cscore", "Impulsivity", "SS")))

Comment: From the help page for `?fisher.test` it makes it clear it expects non-negative integers. It sounds like this is the wrong test for your data. If you want recommendations for alternative statistical tests, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Its part of my coursework so I'm not sure if I could apply a function to it which wouldn't necessarily impact the results

Comment: Maybe `fisher.test` isn't the test you intended to use. The term "fishers discriminant" could be interpreted at linear discriminator analysis. Maybe you were trying to do something like this instead: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/linear-discriminant-analysis-in-r/. If this is for course work, ask your instructor for further guidance because we have no idea what's expected for the course.

Comment: I have added a matrix into the question which I have formed which has no negative values but I can't get this to run either

Comment: Again, the help file makes it clear that the `fisher.test` function expects "non-negative integers" -- numbers with decimal points will not work.  The `fisher.test` function runs the "fisher exact test" which is meant for counts of observations in different categories. It doesn't work with non-integer data. That's why i was wondering if you have the wrong test with "Fisher" in the name. The man did a lot of there's a lot of stuff named after him.

Comment: We have been learning about the fishers test and the idea is to compare it to the results we have for the kNN algorithm. Any ideas on a different R function I can use on the data to find the fishers discriminant